# Solr does not search data in correct fashion

Tags: solr, solrj, solr4

We have a customer web application, which uses Apache Solr APIs internally. We do not have access to the SolrUI on customer site.
Due to recent changes in Solr at customer end, whenever we try to search the data like

`NAME:PRANAV AND AGE:1`, Solr does not show any results.(shows numFound:0)

whereas when we search

`NAME=PRANAV AND AGE:1`, it gives the result.(shows numFound value greater than 0)

So String searches works with = and numeric search works with :.

But when we search

`NAME=PRA*` , we do not get any result in Solr. (shows numFound:0)

Can someone please advise, what should be changed on Solr side to correct the searches?

We want to have wild card searches (*, ?) to work and also String search should work with : instead of =.

Comment: what is the field type applied for for the field Name? COuld you please try with String field type...which will help you to achieve the exact match as well wild card search...

Comment: `NAME=PRANAV` does not search for `PRANAV` in the `NAME` field - it search for `NAME=PRANAV` in the default search field. This field probably tokenizes the input text on non-alphanumeric characters, so effectively it searches for `NAME` and `PRANAV` in the default search field. When you add the wildcard (`*`) tokenization does not happen and you're searching for `NAME=PRA` in the default search field. This does not work. Since your first query does not work, there doesn't seem to be any value matching `PRANAV` in the `NAME` field. This will depend on analysis.

Comment: If the field type is `string`, only exact matches (including case) will generate a match. In that case `NAME:PRANAV*` should give you all documents where `NAME` starts with `PRANAV`.